# Xamarin forms - change page content depending on button clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, navigation

[image]

I currently have a page where I display some objects in a List view retrieved. I am using DataTemplate to display all of them because the list will grow over time. Now, for each of the object, I want to be able to display a page with some information about each of them. So, architecture will be the same for each page, but the content will be different (Labels, Title) How can I make this happen ?

Currently, each of the objects lead to the same page. I just need to display the content for each one

My object contains the following properties:

```
    public int NewVersionId { get; set; }

    public string HtmlFileName { get; set; }

    public string FeatureName { get; set; }

    public string Date { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public bool IsNew { get; set; }
```

```
<ui:ExtendedListView
                  x:Name="ListOfVersions"
                  Grid.Row="3"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Results}"
                  RowHeight="135">

                    <ui:ExtendedListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="version:NewVersionItem">
                            <ui:ExtendedViewCell
                              SelectedBackgroundColor="Transparent"
                              ShowSeparator="True"
                              Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.ShowVersionSettingsPage, Source={Reference ListOfVersions}}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding .}" >
                                  <ui:ExtendedGrid Margin="15,20">

                                      <ui:ExtendedGrid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                      </ui:ExtendedGrid.RowDefinitions>

                                      <ui:ExtendedStackLayout
                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                        Orientation="Horizontal">

                                          <ui:ExtendedLabel
                                            x:Name="FeatureName"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                            WidthRequest="300"
                                            MaxLines="2"
                                            Text="{Binding FeatureName}"
                                            TextColor="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}"
                                            FontSize="16"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold" />

                                          <Frame
                                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                            WidthRequest="60"
                                            Padding="0,0,0,0"
                                            Margin="0,0,30,0"
                                            CornerRadius="10"
                                            BackgroundColor="#6AC66A"
                                            IsVisible="{Binding IsNew}">
                                              <ui:ExtendedLabel
                                                Text="new"
                                                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                          </Frame>

                                          <Image HorizontalOptions="End"
                                                 VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                 WidthRequest="{DynamicResource NavigationArrowSize}">
                                            <Image.Source>
                                                <FontImageSource FontFamily="GenFont"
                                                    Glyph="{controls:Icon ArrowRight}"
                                                    Size="{DynamicResource NavigationArrowSize}"
                                                    Color="{DynamicResource ForegroundColorSecondary}" />
                                            </Image.Source>
                                          </Image>

                                      </ui:ExtendedStackLayout>

                                      <ui:ExtendedLabel
                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                        Text="{Binding Date}"
                                        TextColor="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}"
                                        FontSize="14" />

                                      <ui:ExtendedLabel
                                        Grid.Row="2"
                                        Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                        Text="{Binding Description}"
                                        TextColor="{DynamicResource ForegroundColor}"
                                        FontSize="14"
                                        MaxLines="2"  />

                                  </ui:ExtendedGrid>
                            </ui:ExtendedViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ui:ExtendedListView.ItemTemplate>

                </ui:ExtendedListView>
```

```
private async void OnShowVersionSettingPageExecute()
        {
            try
            {
                await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(Pages.WhatsNewFeaturePage.Id);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current.Trace("An error has occurred while navigating", e, this);
            }
        }
```

Comment: use a switch statement to determine which detail page to navigate to.  I don't see any particular benefit in having a single page that changes layout based on some property.  You can use the same VM for each page type

Comment: But isn't it bad to have multiple pages ? And will I have to register pages everytime I have a new feature ?

Comment: @PatrickYoussef You should only need 2 pages here... one for the list you are currently showing and the second for a detailed view of the item selected from the list

Comment: Most apps have multiple pages.  You could have one page with multiple ContentViews but that would be the same amount of work.

Comment: Can't I pass an Id bound to each object and then in the details page, I know which object should be displayed ?

Comment: @Bijington Right, but how do I know which one I clicked so I can display the correct content ?

Comment: the selected or tapped event will tell you which Item you selected

Comment: Yes exactly as @Jason said, the item tapped should be the value passed in to your `ShowVersionSettingsPage` command handler

Comment: @Jason As you can see in my xaml code in the <ui:ExtendedviewCell> tag, I have a command parameter, would this work ?

Comment: Yes.  Have you tried it?

Comment: @Jason Yes, in my VM, I have a method that leads to me to my details page, but how can I carry out the object information (featureName, htmlFileName, ...) to my new page?

Comment: pass it on the page constructor - a page is just a C# class.  If you want further help, please post the relevant code

Comment: I added the method that is called on the Command handler at the end of my question. @Jason

Comment: are you using Prism or some other framework?

Comment: Yes, I am using Prism

Comment: that is the kind of information you should include in your post or tags.  See https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/navigation/passing-parameters.html